# Constructing JSON Array

Tags: python, arrays, json, iteration

I want something like this:

```
[
    ('Urbandale paid the Regional Municipality of Ottawa-Carleton "redevelopment" charges',
     {'entities': [(0, 9, 'PLTF')]}),
    ('Urbandale carries on business as a land developer.',
     {'entities': [(0, 9, 'PLTF')]})
    ]
```

I am able to set it as a variable and get it to work, but now I am try to automate constructing the JSON array. This one seems to be in a unconventional format? i.e. why is there a comma after the sentence and not `:`

Anyway it is the format that is required by spacy.
I've tried creating a dictionary then doing json.dumps into a json object, which is a lot easier but what is wanted is an array.

I've looked at this post: [Python - Create array of json objects from for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865013/python-create-array-of-json-objects-from-for-loops) and tried iterating constructively but I just get an invalid syntax error

```
spans = []
for mention in mentions:
    mention = str(mention)
    for f in re.finditer(subj, mention): 
        spans.append(f.span())
train_data = [{mention, "entities": (f.span()[0], f.span()[1], 'PLTF')} for mention, span in zip(mentions, spans)]
```

Edit: using json.load(), TEST_DATA[0][1] (the structure I want) yields pretty much the same result as TRAIN_DATA[0][1] except with the additional () on the inside of the dict. I'm pretty sure its the culprit as I get this error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. So how would I insert that? If I simply put an extra () around it, python parses it and it's removed.

**Solved: Just put an extra []**

Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: syntaxerror points at the : after "entities"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is actually a list of tuples of str as the first element and dict as the second element. Simply put more parenthesis and move your curry bracket.

```
train_data = [(mention, {"entities": (f.span()[0], f.span()[1], 'PLTF')}) for mention, span in zip(mentions, spans)]
```

Comment: OK I stopped getting the syntax error, but I still get this error `'str' object does not support item assignment`. I think the main problem is the array or at least part of it is being read as a string. This part (f.span()[0], f.span()[1], 'PLTF')?? I get only [0, 9, "PLTF"] and not with parenthesis on inside. Also a bunch of places where there should be () there is a []. I'm not sure if I can simply replace those without corrupting the encoding

Comment: Edit: using json.load(), TEST_DATA[0][1] (the structure I want) yields pretty much the same result as TRAIN_DATA[0][1] except with the additional () on the inside of the dict. I'm pretty sure its the culprit as I get this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. So how would I insert that? If I simply put an extra () around it, python parses it and it's removed