# Build JSON object with variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I used this answer [Create array of json objects from for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865013/python-create-array-of-json-objects-from-for-loops) and works really well for "plain" JSON objects, but if I have a nested element is not working correctly, this is my code:

```
story_project=open('json_jira/stories/stories_to_jira_TESTEST.json', 'w+'
#######Projects############
json_projects = []
p_name_a, p_key_a, p_type_a = [], [], []
#######Issues##############
json_issues = []
i_summary_a, i_created_a, i_reporter_a, i_status_a, i_issue_type_a = [], [], [], [], []
#######Custom Fields########
json_custom_field_values = []
cf_field_name_a, cf_field_type_a, cf_value_a = [], [], []

#########The Values################
p_name_a.append("ClubHouseDEV")
p_key_a.append("CLUB")
p_type_a.append("software")

i_summary_a.append("This summary doesn not exist")
i_created_a.append("2017-07-17T02:35:16Z")
i_reporter_a.append("5a02285487c3eb1913c44a80")
i_status_a.append("Open")
i_issue_type_a.append("Milestones")

cf_field_name_a.append("external_id")
cf_field_type_a.append("com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float")
cf_value_a.append(3)

cf_field_name_a.append("Story Points")
cf_field_type_a.append("com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float")
cf_value_a.append(5)
###########Build The JSON##############

json_custom_field_values = [{"fieldName": cf_field_name, "fieldType": cf_field_type, "value": cf_value} for cf_field_name, cf_field_type, cf_value in zip(cf_field_name_a, cf_field_type_a, cf_value_a)]

json_issues = [{"sumamry": i_summary, "created": i_created, "reporter": i_reporter, "status": i_status, "issueType": i_issue_type, "customFieldValues" : json_custom_field_value} for i_summary, i_created, i_reporter, i_status, i_issue_type, json_custom_field_value   in zip(i_summary_a, i_created_a, i_reporter_a, i_status_a, i_issue_type_a, json_custom_field_values)]

json_projects = [{"name": p_name, "key": p_key, "type": p_type, "issues": json_issue} for p_name, p_key, p_type,json_issue   in zip(p_name_a, p_key_a, p_type_a,json_issues)]

json_file = [{"projects": json_project} for json_project  in zip(json_projects)]
json.dump(json_file, story_project)
```

The output should be:

```
{ "projects": [
        {
            "name": "ClubHouseDEV",
            "key": "CLUB",
            "type":"software",
            "issues": 
            [
                {
                    "summary":"This summary doesn not exist",
                    "created":"2017-07-17T02:35:16Z",
                    "reporter":"5a02285487c3eb1913c44a80",
                    "status":"Open",
                    "issueType":"Milestones",
                    "customFieldValues": 
                    [
                        {
                            "fieldName": "external_id",
                            "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
                            "value": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "fieldName": "Story Points",
                            "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    ],
                    "labels" : ["ch_epics"],
                    "updated": "2017-07-17T02:35:16Z"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

But it is:

```
[{"projects": [{"name": "ClubHouseDEV", "key": "CLUB", "type": "software", "issues": {"sumamry": "This summary doesn not exist", "created": "2017-07-17T02:35:16Z", "reporter": "5a02285487c3eb1913c44a80", "status": "Open", "issueType": "Milestones", "customFieldValues": {"fieldName": "external_id", "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float", "value": 3}}}]}]
```

As you can see it only added one value on the nested "Custom Field Values", how can I add all the values.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve id: Build the deepest level, then integrated it with the level up and so on, the output was the expected.

```
###########Build The JSON##############
for cf_field_name, cf_field_type, cf_value in zip(cf_field_name_a, cf_field_type_a, cf_value_a):
    json_custom_field_values = {}
    json_custom_field_values["fieldName"] = cf_field_name
    json_custom_field_values["fieldType"] = cf_field_type
    json_custom_field_values["value"] = cf_value
    cf_data.append(json_custom_field_values)

for i_summary, i_created, i_reporter, i_status, i_issue_type in zip(i_summary_a, i_created_a, i_reporter_a, i_status_a, i_issue_type_a):
    json_issues = {}
    json_issues["summary"] = i_summary
    json_issues["created"] = i_created
    json_issues["reporter"] =i_reporter
    json_issues["status"] = i_status
    json_issues["issueType"] = i_issue_type
    # json_issues["customFieldValues"] = [{"fieldName": cf_field_name, "fieldType": cf_field_type, "value": cf_value} for cf_field_name, cf_field_type, cf_value in zip(cf_field_name_a, cf_field_type_a, cf_value_a)]
    json_issues["customFieldValues"] = cf_data
    issues_data.append(json_issues)

for p_name, p_key, p_type in zip(p_name_a, p_key_a, p_type_a):
    json_projects = {}
    json_projects["name"] = p_name
    json_projects["key"] = p_key
    json_projects["type"] = p_type
    json_projects["issues"] = issues_data
    projects_data.append(json_projects)

json_dict["projects"] =  projects_data
json.dump(json_dict, story_project)
```